# Prevent apt from overwriting a package manually installed

Tags: ubuntu, apt, debian-based

Ubuntu Bionic provides Protobuf 3.0.0, and I'd like to use the latest release, 3.6.1.

I've gone and built the Protobuf sources and installed them with the prefix `/usr`, so the files end up in the same place that the official Ubuntu package puts them.

However, if I subsequently issue an `apt-get install protobuf-compiler`, it will overwrite my `protoc` binary with the older version. (Actually, `protobuf-compiler` is specified as a build dependency of a package I'm building with `mk-build-deps`.)

I've tried using `apt-mark manual protobuf-compiler` to tell `apt` that I've manually installed it, but it tells me I can't do that because the package is not installed. (How does it determine this? I don't know.)

Similarly `apt-mark hold` does not prevent the binary from being overwritten.

What is the correct way to install this software, have `apt` understand that the dependency is satisfied, and not have it overwrite my newer build with the old one?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be simply to change the installation directory of `protobuf-compiler` 3.6.1.

Instead of installing to `/usr` you could install to some other directory. On my work PC (on which I don't have sudo rights) I install to a directory I created called `/data/local_installs`. Then update the path environment variable

```sh
export PATH=/data/local_installs:$PATH
```

and you're ready to go.

With this method you don't have to worry about what `apt` is doing, as the `protobuf-compiler` kept in `/data/local_installs` will always be found in your path before the `apt` controlled version in `/usr`